# Show only the filename in XFCE panel buttons

Tags: xubuntu, xfce

Often I have several files open in mousepad at the same time, and if each file is in a deep path, all of the XFCE window buttons show the same thing, "/home/mike...", "/home/mike/..." , "/home/mike...".

Can XFCE be configured to show the filename with out the path in the window buttons? Can this be done for all applications, e.g. suppose I had three gumeric files open rather than text file in mousepad, and to be able to see the filename without path?

I've tried "Grouping" the windows as per the Window Buttons properties but the length of the visible part of the path is the same and it starts at my home directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The names of the items in the XFCE Panel are controlled by the actual application itself, if it has the setting.  I have one example below since you mentioned MousePad.

In MousePad, Go to *Edit -> Preferences*.  Then in the Window tab, deselect `Show full filename in title bar`.  Then press Close.

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! I had the idea that XFCE was in charge of deciding what to display in the buttons, but it seems to be thing which is controlled separately per app as you've pointed out. I checked gnumeric and it indeed does this already.